# Pyinstaller cant find setuptools

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, setuptools

I am trying to install Pyinstaller 3.6 using Pip 20.0.2 with Python 3.7.4 in an Anaconda3 environment but it always says it cant find the setuptools dependency, despite it showing up with 'pip list' as setuptools 46.1.3.

key points:

1. Machine doesn't have access to internet so if it cant find the package, it will fail.
2. Tried the following versions of the libraries; pip (10.0.01 and 20.0.2), pyinstaller (3.5 and 3.6), setuptools (41.0.0, 45.0.0, 46.1.3)
3. All installs where done through the anaconda prompt with admin access.
4. all packages have been downloaded from PyPi
5. installed as 'pip install *name_of_wheel.whl*'

Comment: What does `pip -V` return?

Comment: pip 20.0.2 from c:\tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)